# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet [/SpringmvcDemo] threw load() exception

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have this problem with a springmvc project ,I imported all the spring jars i need through build path,this result in the above problem.But if i import all the jars into the WEB-INF/lib ,then i can't open the tomcat at all.Any one knows how to solve this?I've google a lot yet found nothing helpful...
[when i copy the jars in the libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su4uR.png)

[through build jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aer48.png)

Comment: Add exceptions as text not as link to an image

Comment: Use maven or gradle as dependency management tool for building spring applications

Comment: In your fist sceenshot you see that the commons-lang.jar is Issing in your classpath

Comment: Thank you for your tips , and I will be cautious next time I post the question.

Answer (score 0):

1.Right click on your project in your ID.
2.Click on Properties
3.Click on Deployment Assembly Tab in the left
4.Click Add...
5.Click on Java Build Path Entries
6.Select Maven Dependencies
7.Redeploy Spring MVC application to Tomcat again
8.Restart Tomcat